# how to compare the difference between two similar tables datapoint by datapoint in r

Tags: r

I have a table (df1) that looks like this:

```
I           id col.3 col.4 col.5 col.6 col.7 col.8
M   Chr18_1369     G     G     T     G     G     G
M  Chr18_54979     G     N     A     N     G     G
M Chr18_187626     C     T     N     T     C     C
M Chr18_196254     C     C     G     C     N     G
M Chr18_224569     A     A     C     N     C     C
M Chr18_275670     T     T     C     C     T     T
```

There are some missing data points represented by "N" in df1. After imputation, the missing data "N" would be replaced by a letter. the output is df2 as:

```
I           id col.3 col.4 col.5 col.6 col.7 col.8
M   Chr18_1369     G     G     T     G     G     G
M  Chr18_54979     G     G     A     G     G     G
M Chr18_187626     C     T     T     T     C     C
M Chr18_196254     C     C     G     C     C     G
M Chr18_224569     A     A     C     A     C     C
M Chr18_275670     T     T     C     C     T     T
```

I have another data frame (df3)

```
I           id col.3 col.4 col.5 col.6 col.7 col.8
M   Chr18_1369     G     G     T     G     G     G
M  Chr18_54979     G     G     A     A     G     G
M Chr18_187626     C     T     C     T     C     C
M Chr18_196254     C     C     G     C     C     G
M Chr18_224569     A     A     C     C     C     C
M Chr18_275670     T     T     C     C     T     T
```

The df3 has the same structure as df2 but some character values may be different in the corresponding locations of missing data "N" in df1. For example, df2[2,6]=="G",but df3[2,6]=="A", and df2[3,5]=="T",df3[3,5]=="C" ...
 I want to calculate the difference rate between df2 and df3. The formula is:

```
U <- length(which(df1 =="N", arr.ind=TRUE))
Diff = length(difference(df2,df3))/U
```

I don't know how to get the length(difference(df2,df3)). I need an elegant script for this task. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sum( df2 == df3 )

does not work?

Comment: Or, to get that as a proportion, `sum(df3==df2)/prod(dim(df2))`.

Comment: the script for this task: U <- which(df1 == "N", arr.ind=TRUE);
accuracy <- sum(df2[U]==df3[U])/length(U)